# How to use jQuery to call an ASP.NET web service?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services

I'm trying to use jQuery to get data from an ASP.NET web service (SharePoint Server 2007 lists.asmx), but any call to a web service will really help as a first step in that direction.

Comment: How would an ASP.NET service be any different from a service running on Tomcat?  In other words: I don't think it matters at all what software the server is running.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I use this method as a wrapper so that I can send parameters. Also using the variables in the top of the method allows it to be minimized at a higher ratio and allows for some code reuse if making multiple similar calls.

```
function InfoByDate(sDate, eDate){
    var divToBeWorkedOn = "#AjaxPlaceHolder";
    var webMethod = "http://MyWebService/Web.asmx/GetInfoByDates";
    var parameters = "{'sDate':'" + sDate + "','eDate':'" + eDate + "'}";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
        },
        error: function(e){
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");
        }
    });
}
```

Please note that this requires the 3.5 framework to expose JSON webmethods that can be consumed in this manner.

Comment: is this line:
"var webMethod = 'http://MyWebService/Web.asmx/GetInfoByDates'"
missing a semi-colon on purpose?

Comment: Is there a way to actually view the error message? mine keeps saying unavailable but I need to view the actual error, thank you

Comment: if you use firebug or the console in chrome just store "e" in a variable and then inspect it. i.e. window.ZZZ = e;

Comment: @Bobby, I have follow the steps mentioned in your answer and I am able to call Web service. Its working fine in chrome, but when I tried the same one in firefox, I am getting 0 in response, do you have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: And how to get parameters on   /Web.asmx/GetInfoByDates  ??

Comment: I was wondering if we should put this code inside the HTML and use <script> tag around it?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example to call your webservice using jQuery.get:

```
$.get("http://domain.com/webservice.asmx", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
  function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });
```

In the example above, we call "webservice.asmx", passing two parameters: name and time. Then, getting the service output in the call back function.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about that specific SharePoint web service, but you can decorate a page method or a web service with `<WebMethod()>` (in VB.NET) to ensure that it serializes to JSON. You can probably just wrap the method that webservice.asmx uses internally, in your own web service.

Dave Ward has [a nice walkthrough](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'data.asmx/getText',
 data: {'argInput' : 'input arg(s)'},
 complete: function(xData, status) {
 $('#txt').html($(xData.responseXML).text()); // result
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a decent example in *[jQuery AJAX and ASMX](http://www.sonerdy.com/jquery-ajax-and-asmx/)* on using the jQuery AJAX call with asmx web services...

There is a line of code to uncommment in order to have it return JSON.

Comment: Link is 404 not found.  It's a good idea to always include the main content in the answer in case the site owner suddenly wins the lottery, divorces his wife and moves to Bahamas.

Answer (score 1):

[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) is a jQuery library which abstracts SharePoint's Web Services and makes them easier to use

It is [certified](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Glossary#Certification) for SharePoint 2007

The list of supported operations for Lists.asmx could be found [here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices)

### Example

In this example, we're grabbing all of the items in the Announcements list and displaying the Titles in a bulleted list in the tasksUL div:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite often use ajaxpro along with jQuery. ajaxpro lets me call .NET functions from JavaScript and I use jQuery for the rest.