# Can you use jQuery to connect to a .NET Webservice?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services

Is it possible to use jQuery to connect to a .NET webservice?
Maybe something I can pass a wsdl url too.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unlikely anyone will answer, I'll just do my part to back-link humanity's knowledge.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service) is specifically for ASP.NET, but there will be overlap with what is suggested by the answers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)