# How to call a web service from jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I want to call a webservice from jQuery. How can I do that?

Comment: It is somewhat related to Stack Overflow question *[How to use jQuery to call an ASP.NET web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service/230605)*.

Comment: I suggest closing the question, if this is answered sufficiently well in the link I posted below

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can make an AJAX request like any other requests:

```
$.ajax( {
type:'Get',
url:'http://mysite.com/mywebservice',
success:function(data) {
 alert(data);
}

})
```

Comment: Please correct the spelling of the onSuccess handler ... from sucess to success

Comment: that good but how about when you need cross domain

Comment: @kta, then you will need jsonp

Answer (score 7):

EDIT:

The OP was not looking to use cross-domain requests, but jQuery supports JSONP as of v1.5. See [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), specificically the `crossDomain` parameter.

<del>The regular jQuery Ajax requests will not work cross-site, so if you want to query a remote RESTful web service, you'll probably have to make a proxy on your server and query that with a jQuery get request. See [this site](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) for an example.</del>

<del>If it's a SOAP web service, you may want to try the [jqSOAPClient plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient).</del>

Answer (score 3):

I blogged about how to consume a WCF service using jQuery:

http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/creating-a-webservice-proxy-with-jquery/

The post shows how to create a service proxy straight up in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Incase people have a problem like myself following Marwan Aouida's answer ... the code has a small typo. Instead of "success" it says "sucess" change the spelling and the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, this return value fails with jQuery Ajax GET:

```
return Response.status(200).entity(pojoObj).build();
```

But this works:

```
ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(200).entity(pojoObj);
return rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();

----
```

Full class:

```
@Path("/password")
public class PasswordStorage {
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getRole() {
        Contact pojoObj= new Contact();
        pojoObj.setRole("manager");

        ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(200).entity(pojoObj);
        return rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();

        //Fails jQuery: return Response.status(200).entity(pojoObj).build();
    }
}
```