# jQuery and WebServices

Tags: jquery

I want to call this WS http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCountries

What is the best possible way to do it using jQuery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861784/how-to-call-a-web-service-from-jquery/861808#861808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make Cross-Domain calls with jQuery you'll either have set-up a "proxy" file on your own server which fetches the remote contents and sends them to local jQuery or you need the webservice to support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP)

Comment: Errr can't you just use ajax GET...http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Comment: Can you give an example with the above webservice i posted..it gives permission denied

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using the ajax method (either POST or GET).
Here i use GET as all remote (not on the same domain) requests should be specified as GET. I also provide a callback method to show the result as an alert.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx",
   data: "op=GetCountries",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Result: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Comment: I did it exactly as you suggested and got the 'Permission Denied' error

Comment: Ah ok, use the jQuery.getJSON method instead like duckyflip stated: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

- http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/