# javascript windows alert with redirect function

Tags: php, javascript, html

.guys I have the following code:

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
        </SCRIPT>");
```

what i want to do is that when i click ok on the windows.alert the page will be redirected to a my edit.php.

or how is it possible to create a javascript which will execute an insert query.

Comment: Jquery has built it means for calling server side code directly.  You probably want to look at this previous question as a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861784/how-to-call-a-web-service-from-jquery.  Also if you are interested in blocking the client side during your insert you can take a look at the jquery plugin blockui http://jquery.malsup.com/block/.

Comment: @bwmfsu Sheez. When you have a platinum hammer, you really make all problems look like nails? jQuery is massive overkill here.

Comment: @mplungjan I misunderstood the question.  I thought the question was about hitting an insert asynchronously maybe reading too much into this excerpt from the question _javascript which will execute an insert query_  I have been doing a lot of this within the last few weeks so that's where my mind is.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Alert will block the program flow so you can just write the following.

```
echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Succesfully Updated');
    window.location.href='http://someplace.com';
    </script>");
```

Comment: That way is not recommended, you don't send the header so you better write `exit;` after `echo`

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to redirect the user after the alert, do this:

```
echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
          window.alert('Succesfully Updated');
          window.location.href='<URL to redirect to>';
       </script>");
```

Comment: document.location is deprecated and supposedly read-only. It does work but is not designed to do it

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated'); window.location = './edit.php';</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you also want to consider non-javascript users:

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
           window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
           window.location.href='http://someplace.com';
       </SCRIPT>
       <NOSCRIPT>
           <a href='http://someplace.com'>Successfully Updated. Click here if you are not redirected.</a>
       </NOSCRIPT>");
```