# Java variables inside Javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I have a variable declared outside my javascript function which gets its value from session.

```
   String elementID = session.getAttribute("elementID");
   <SCRIPT>
        var a = "123"
        elementID = a;
   </SCRIPT>
```

Will this work out? i need to assign the value "123" to the string variable elementID.

Comment: JSP is server side. Javascript is client side. **That's the first thing you need to understand.**

Comment: In other words, **no** it will not work.

Comment: It is will just fine if you serialize the value. But you definitely need to understand the difference between those two languages and why that wouldn't fundamentally work.

Comment: It's quite unfortunate that JavaScript has "Java" in its name. You wouldn't expect C++ to share its variables with JavaScript, would you?

Comment: If you are generating the Javascript as part of a page that is being generated by Java (such as in a JSP), then you can certainly embed values from Java into the Javascript -- at that point, you are merely assembling some text which is going to be sent down to the browser -- but this is not the right syntax for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not simply possible, since Java runs server-side and JavaScript client-side.

You can't assume that the JavaScript (that won't be evaluated until it's on the client) knowns anything about Java. It doesn't.

Comment: Actually, [it is possible to invoke Java functions from JavaScript in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536455/calling-java-method-in-javascript). Of course, the JavaScript and Java code will need to be written in separate files.