# Call Java method from Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [calling java methods in javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649125/calling-java-methods-in-javascript-code)

It's possible to call a java method from javascript? I'm using phonegap but push notification funcionality is not integrated so I've decidet to create the part of Push made of Java and then i want to call from Javascript to java several functions. It's possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649125/calling-java-methods-in-javascript-code

Comment: But it's not an applet it's an android app

Comment: So? Java is cross-platform and highly portable, why would we provide a different answer to the same question on every platform?

Comment: @tylerHeiks because i want to create the app using phonegap and this is the only part that phonegap is not adapted :)

Comment: From the tags, I'm assuming what you want to do is develop a "native" app with HTML/JS using PhoneGap (ugh), except you want to use some non-JS component in it. I believe you'll have to write a PhoneGap plugin: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins. (I haven't really used PhoneGap though, so that's pretty much all I've got.)

Comment: If @millimoose has assumed correctly then this question is far too broad.

Comment: @millimoose exact! It is the thing!

Comment: @TylerHeiks Not as much broad as "hit the documentation then come back with where that leads you"

Comment: @millimoose I meant if he was going to ask how to make a plugin for phonegap in his native code.

Answer (score 1):

use [Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) for your Javascript to Java Interaction

> DWR is a Java library that enables Java on the server and JavaScript
>   in a browser to interact and call each other as simply as possible.
>
> DWR is Easy Ajax for Java

Comment: but not call javascript from java. I want to call java from javascript

Comment: @MarcOrtiz yes sorry I read wrong see edited post

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the java code it may be possible to translate it to javascript, providing javascript methods that can be called from your existing javascript.

The [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/overview) compiler can be used to generate javascript from java code, but there are limitations on which java libraries you can use.

Since you've mentioned phonegap, this may also be useful to you: [gwt-phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/).

Comment: And it's not possible to only call methods and functions?

Comment: java methods from javascript on the same client without some sort of translation? not unless there is some android functionality that I'm unaware of. try tagging the question with `android`.

Answer (score -1):

`Javascript` runs on client browser and `java` code runs on server except `Applet` so it is not possible to call directly java from `javascript` unless you use some other way (HTTP)where you make a call to server with some paramter and then based on parameter you can call java code

Comment: This is just completely incorrect.
EDIT: Not COMPLETELY wrong anymore now that you've edited your answer but yes you can call java methods from jScript.

Comment: -1: You can call methods exposed by Java applets on a web page from Javascript. You can also embed a Javascript interpreter in Java. In Android, you embed WebKit in Java apps and can presumably have some integration between the two. (I imagine there's at least an equivalent of iOS' [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Please check I've clearly written 'Directly you can not call java from javascript'

Comment: @amicngh Without defining the word "directly". It's still wrong even with the edit.

Comment: @TylerHeiks I've not changed this statement.

Comment: @amicngh That statement is vague enough to be meaningless though.

Comment: In particular, the OP mentions PhoneGap, the *entire point* of which is to expose native APIs to Javascript. (Assuming that's what he actually wants to do, which is unclear from the question.)

Comment: @millimoose : I missed PhoneGap tag.

Comment: @amicngh Your blanket statement was wrong anyway, even without PhoneGap being mentioned. "You can't do this except for all the cases when you can" isn't a very useful answer, and should be a clue that you should instead ask the OP whether his case is in fact one of "all the cases".