# Capture Java function return value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

I have a simple Java function which return Integer:

```
class TestClass {
     private int testMethod(int a, int b){
     // Some code
     return a + b;
     }
}
```

How can I call this function from JavaScript and store the return value in variable?

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649125/calling-java-methods-in-javascript-code). It helps explain what you need to know.