# How to increment a value after clicking a button on jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, webtop

These are my JSP panels:

```
<dmf:panel name='panel43main'>
        <h2>
        <p style="text-indent:100px;text-align:justify">
              <dmf:dateinput name = 'BoiDate' tooltipnlsid='MSG_DATE'/> <dmf:button name='createpanel' cssclass="buttonLink" label='Add Date' onclick='onAddPanel' height='16' tooltipnlsid="MSG_OK_TIP"/>
        </p>
        </h2>
</dmf:panel>
```

Is there a way where when i click on the button(createpanel), ill increment a value inside the onAddPanel function? Thank you guys.

Comment: Yes. `your_value++;`

Comment: How do i do it here in my code? having a base counter 0. @NathanP.

Comment: I can't see your JS code

Comment: public void onAddPanel(Button button, ArgumentList arg){
  (panel+counter).setVisible(true);
  counter++;
 }
@NathanP.

Comment: Is `onAddPanel` a JavaScript function, or a Java one ?

Comment: Java sir @NathanP.

Comment: Okay sir @NathanP. can you give me an example how i can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling java methods in javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649125/calling-java-methods-in-javascript-code)