# Sending an Email from onclick JavaScript function from SMTP java class and jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, smtp

Good Morning,

I hope someone will be of great help :)

I Just want to know how i will write the JavaScript :)

I currently have text field, and a button, but i want the button to send the message box info to an email address onclick, but im not quite sure how to do the JavaScript part, i want to know how i can call my Java Class in the JS and then then do the onclick function to send the Email.

Thanks so much in advance

```
public class SendMailTLS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "diamantengoud@gmail.com";
    final String password = "********";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("diamantengoud@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("jp.pretorius@bmgi.co.za"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


<form  method="post" enctype="text/plain" >
                            <h1>Send a Message</h1>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <form class="form-horizontal"  a>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                                        <input type="" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                                        <input type="" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" >
                                    <label for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                                    <textarea  class="form-control"  style="height: 300px" id="inputMessage" rows=""></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-50">
                                        <button onclick="" value="Send" id="send-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: You could create a servlet out of the java code that you have and make an ajax call in the javascript. Do some googling on how to make ajax calls and creating servlets.

Comment: Please look at this question:
[Calling Java Methods in Javascript Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649125/calling-java-methods-in-javascript-code)