# Is it possible to use a Java method in a jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a class `ManXML` that has a method that returns an array of strings `String[] : getArrayTemas()`. I want to use that output as a variable in the script of my jsp.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    BindControls();
});

function BindControls() {
    const BD = new ManXML("BaseDados");

    var Temas = BD.getArrayTemas();

    $('#tbTemas').autocomplete({
        source : Temas,
        minLength : 0,
        scroll : true
    }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    });
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Is the class included in your war file?

Comment: Ajax would be your best choice.

Comment: Are you really trying to call from the JSP? Or from Javascript (which runs in the browser)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649125/calling-java-methods-in-javascript-code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. 
In my answer, I suppose your getArrayTemas() is a static method.

At first, you have to import your class in the jsp and then you can use your static method:

```
<%@page import="x.y.z.ManXML"%> 

<%
   String [] arrayTernas = ManXML.getArrayTemas();

%>
```

Finally you can use your arrayTernas with `<%=arrayTernas%>` or `${arrayTernas}` (if you are using JSTL)

Comment: But the class needs the constructor, the string that recieves from parameter

Comment: I tried something like.... <%@page import="Parte2.ManXML"%> 

  <%
     ManXMLBD = new ManXML("BaseDados");
     String [] arrayTemas = BD.getArrayTemas();

  %>

Comment: As I said, I supposed that your method was static. It's not a good practice creating a new instance in a JSP. Aren't you able to convert your method to a static one?

Comment: You could also inject an instance to call methods on with `request.setAttribute` from the controller code that dispatched to that JSP (assuming there is one).

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: And I cant convert into a static one