# Calling Synchronous Web Service in Java from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, html, web-services

I have a requirement of calling a web service built in Java to be called from an HTML page via Java-script.

I have tried the code sample available at the following URL: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14610/Calling-Web-Services-from-HTML-Pages-using-JavaScr#

```
  <html>
  <head>
   <title>Hello World</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
     var iCallID;
     function InitializeService(){
      service.useService(http://localhost:1394/MyWebService.asmx?wsdl, 
    "HelloWorldService");
      service.HelloWorldService.callService("HelloWorld");
     }
     function ShowResult(){
      alert(event.result.value);//Output: Undefined
     }
    </script>
   </head>
  <body onload="InitializeService()" id="service" 
    style="behavior:url(webservice.htc)" onresult="ShowResult()"> </body>
 </html>
```

The web service is running and has been tested via a Weblogic inbuilt test client.

Please suggest some JS code for calling a webservice with String Parameters

Comment: Vote to close. Please comment on why whatever you've posted as sample does not work for you. Also consider using more mainstream JQuery.ajax to make calls ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861784/how-to-call-a-web-service-from-jquery )

Comment: Ugh, that code smells like IE-only...

Comment: The Line: service.useService(http://localhost:1394/MyWebService.asmx?wsdl, "HelloWorldService"); poses a problem.
My Web Service never gets a hits and the request is lost in mid way. then the next line onwards, the code starts giving undefined for the response(Line: alert(event.result.value);)

Comment: Please suggest any other code that might help in calling a Web service from Java script with parameters and the WSDL URL is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX). Be careful though, it only allows requests on the same domain (browsers limitation). If you want cross-domain support, either use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (if the webservice allows it), or use a server as a proxy, so that:

```
Javascript -> Server on same domain -> WebService
```

Comment: Please provide Code Snippet so that i can try out the same.

Comment: AJAX is a vast subject, and I don't even know whether you need the snippet in javascript or not (cross-domain or not? jsonp allowed or not?).

Comment: Hi Florian Margaine, the thing is that i need to create a simple HTML page for demo purposes only and need to call the web-service through the HTML page. the simplest i guess will be javascript. Please help with the simplest possible solution