# how to Call a specific method of my Web Service from java script?

Tags: javascript, web-services

i am trying to call a web service from my pure HTML page using java script.
i had successfully created a web service using java on net beans. now i want to call a method from that web service using java script with sending some parameters to the web Service, i had tried so far but not succeed yet.
i had successfully called the method using jsp page, but i need to do it by using simple html page.

i had seen an example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861784/how-to-call-a-web-service-from-jquery) but it is not working with me. :(

can you please give me some example, so that i come to know how to call a specific method of my web service from java script with sending some parameters to the web service.

thanks in advance.

EDIT

my script

```
    function validateForm(frm)
{ 
document.forms[0].action="http://localhost:8084/Web_Service_Example/CircleFunctions?"
document.forms[0].method="post"
document.forms[0].submit()
}
```

my CircleFunctions method

```
public class CircleFunctions {
public int sum()

{
    int a = 20;
    int b = 40;

    int c = a+b;

    return c;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the request to the same domain?  Or are you trying to call a web service from a different location?

Comment: @JustinBeckwith i am trying to call a web service from a different location, i.e. from my local server or system.

Comment: Heh, you just said two different things :-)  Could you post your JavaScript?

Comment: @Justin Beckwith Actualy upto now i didn't wrote any java script, i just doing R&D for that. i had tried the answer which is given by Satya but it is showing me the XML page only.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.forms[0].action="http://localhost:8080/webservice/services/add"
document.forms[0].method="get"
document.forms[0].submit()
```

Comment: it shows me direct XML page of web service. i neeed to call directly function of that web service.

Comment: thnks for change in code, it is calling my web service but not showing the output, is says "Hi there, this is an AXIS service!" but when i directly run my web service it shows the output. can u please help me a bit more.

Comment: can you paste what is the actual URL you need to call for your ws

Comment: as far as I can see you are not passing any param to add method , so I have updated my code to call add directly try that

Comment: still the same.. :( "Hi there, this is an AXIS service!"

Comment: when you paste this URL http://localhost:8080/webservice/services/add in your browser what do you get. Also paste this URL http://localhost:8080/webservice/add and let me know the output of these 2

Comment: on first link the error is same that is "Hi there, this is an AXIS service!" and on second one the error 404 (The requested resource (/webservice/add) is not available).

Comment: localhost:8080/webservice/services/add/sum paste this URL and let me know the output

Comment: Error 404(The requested resource (/webservice/add/sum) is not available). :(

Comment: paste your WSDL pl localhost:8080/webservice/services/add?WSDL

Comment: not working yar... :( :(  error is same that is "Hi there, this is an AXIS service!" is there any other way to do that..??