# Using webservice in Chrome extension for accessing user information

Tags: web-services, google-chrome-extension

I want to make an extension for Chrome that customers have to enter their username and password. Then after that they can view their account information by the extension instead of log in to website.

But firstly I'm beginner in developing Chrome extension then after I read some articles about it, now I don't know Where I can start?

**Secondly my big problem is using web service in my extension because I have to get customer user/pass and send them to my web service (.net) to get information.**

I appreciate you if you give me your ideas/sample code/tutorial/...

Answer (score 0):

> But firstly I'm beginner in developing Chrome extension then after I read some articles about it, now I don't know Where I can start?

Start from [hello worlds](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html), of course. I would recommend refreshing your knowledge of HTML/CSS and Javascript, as Chrome extensions are essentially local web pages.

But before you dive into new technology, think if you really need to do this as a Chrome extension. Maybe a simple set of webpages will be a better (and cross-browser) choice? Do you really need chrome.* API? Maybe you can share some additional details, like why did you decide to go with Chrome extension in the first place.

Comment: thanks, I started from Hello World, and I'm swimming now. Reason for using a chrome extension is because of my Boss! He wants his customers can load their information via an extension from our database and view their information in summarize instead of log in our website for gathering info. Actually it will be a facility for customers.

Comment: If you really need to go that way, ok then. You can use some Javascript framework to consume your webservice and do something. It will be the same as writing a common web-page with such functionality. And whatever you do - don't use local storage to store users' passwords.

Comment: What javascript framework? Can you give me a chance to find an example about it?

Comment: Well, RESTful services are pretty easy to consume. For example, you can use [jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861784/how-to-call-a-web-service-from-jquery) (personally, my favorite). Consuming a SOAP webservice would be a little more complicated, but you can google something like "javascript SOAP".