# Using AJAX to call a .NET webservice method that takes a custom object

Tags: web-services, jquery, asmx

I'm using a third party webservice. The service exposes a custom class which I'm supposed to pass as a parameter when calling the method I need. That's not a problem, but is there any way i can use jquery and ajax to make a call to that web service method?

Does the question make sense? I'm kind of new to this so please let me know if more information is necessary. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered quite a few times in this site. They even have examples of calls.

But the basic answer is yes. Look into the following jquery methods to do it.

Check out jquery ajax method:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Even easier you can use the get or post methods as well:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/