# Getting data from web service in ASP.NET by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service which is returning me a list [better say a table with 5 columns and could be n number of rows.]

How can I get the data from the web service by jQuery and show it in the table structure in UI.

- Input Parameter for web service: customer Id
- Output Parameter: ProductId, ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductURL, ProductAvailable

I am unable to find examples related to this functionality on internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery to call an asp.net web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use jQuery.ajax.
[How to use jQuery to call an ASP.NET web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230401/337294)
http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx

Also, I have written a plugin that serializes the data to pass to your web service and contains some samples. you can download it at:  http://www.4shared.com/file/8hHJll-R/Pagemethod-2.html

Comment: If you see that that's a duplicate, vote to close, and post some links as comment

Answer (score 3):

Check out these links:--

http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183.aspx