# html button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

i am using html in asp page where i have to use html button. but the problem is i want to do the coding on html button in c#. but by using html button i cant do that.. is there any other way to do so..i am using html button as:

```
 <button id="MyButton" runat="server" onserverclick="MyButton_ServerClick" >
   </button>
```

if i double-click on the html button from .aspx page it generates the code as function under script as:

```
 function MyButton_onclick() {

        }
```

what can i do for this..

Comment: What's wrong with using `<asp:Button/>`? If you want to handle the code on the server-side it will have to do a Post.

Comment: @graham clark: but my page is in html and if i use <asp:button>, then in reading html page it is giving an error..

Comment: even more a problem if your site is xy.html as they are not processed by asp.net

Comment: your page is .html or .aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to call a .net WebService to do stuff on the server deepending on what you want to achieve.

[Here an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

Make AJAX request like this :

```
$('#Button').click(function() {
    $.ajax( {
    type:'Get',
    url:'http://mysite.com/mywebservice',
    success:function(data) {
     alert(data);
    }

    })

});
```