# html button on .cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, event-handling

i am using html button in .aspx page. but i want to use the button_click event on .cs page..

i am adding html button as:

```
<button id="button1" runat="server" onclick="Submit_Click">  
    Send  
    </button>
```

and on .cs page i am usng:

```
 protected void Submit_Click(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ggg");
        }
```

i don't want to use asp button ..
and this is not calling the event from .cs page..

how this can be done..

Comment: possible duplicate of [html button in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213811/html-button-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `onserverclick` instead of the `onclick` method as this is a client side event of the HTML button control.

```
<button id="button1" runat="server" onserverclick="Submit_Click">  
Send  
</button>
```

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar:i had also used that but it is not calling the event from .cs page

Comment: It should I have just check it my end and it works perfectly.

Comment: can you put break point and check whether its event fired or not?

Comment: You have to put this in server side form tag.

Comment: any reason you are not using the <asp:Button ... /> intead of the basic html button?

Comment: Any how , if he want to use HTML button control, he can do the same like asp control with HTML control. I have just tested this solution and it works to me.

Comment: @ muhammad akhtar: another problem arises, as i run the page it is giving an error "'Submit_Click' is not a member of 'ASP.theme3_aspx'."..

Comment: @ muhammad akhtar:  as i remove "<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MailCham.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">" tags to make it html it is giving errors....

Comment: I don't have an idea about this issue, but I have not getting any issue in the testing.