# Access denied when calling web service from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to call a Web Service using Jquery.
i found this example  from this site : 
[How to use jQuery to call an ASP.NET web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service)

i modified it to my use :

```
function InfoByDate(aUrl){
    var divToBeWorkedOn = '#AjaxPlaceHolder';
    var webMethod = 'http://MyWebService/Web.asmx/GetInfoByDates'
    var parameters = "{'sUrl':'" + aUrl + "'}"

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {    
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
        },
        error: function(e){
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");              
        }
    });
}
```

Now i get back a js error access denied!
my web service  is located in the same domain so cross domain is not relevant.
Can someone help me with that issue?
Cheers 
NirNiroN

Comment: Is the webservice located on a different domain than the webpage calling it? If so you are hitting the SOP(same origin policy) problem.

Comment: give a little more info. is the call to the server made ? can you inspect it with firebug ? is the server giving a response code or something or nothing is executed and you just get a js error like "access denided" with no error code or line info or anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JavaScript and your not calling the web-service from your own domain, then it wont be allowed. You can use JSONP for cross domain calls however, so try to use that.

You can read up on it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: my web service is in the same domain but i always get Access deined

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling this from? If you're not on the same domain (i.e. "mywebservice"), it won't work as you can't do cross-domain ajax calls like that.

If this is the case, I suggest looking into the various options available to you (CORS on the server, using a reverse proxy on the 'client' machine, or JSONP).

Comment: Agian my webservice is on the same domain..is it a permission issue?

Comment: Sounds like it, yes. Can you call the web service from other clients? I would test it with SoapUI if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Is the webservice available on the same server? Cross server requests are not allowed with Ajax and your webservice must be in the same domain as your JavaScript code to allow it to work.