# Consuming Java Webservice with JQuery, knowing only the WSDL location

Tags: jquery, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl

in the past I already successfully consumed .Net Webservices with jQuery. However now I'm trying to do the same with Java Webservices and I can't figure out how.

In Eclipse I created a new dynamic web project that includes the following example class:

```
public class MessagesService {

public int checkForMessages(String email, String password){

    return 42;
}
```

From this class I created a Web Service by using the Eclipse integrated guide. It created me a WSDL file under the directory WebContent/wsdl. Now I can easily access the WSDL from my browser typing in: http://localhost:8080/MyProject/wsdl/MessagesService.wsdl

Now that I want to call the checkForMessages method I don't really know what to enter in the URL field:

```
  function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: Url,
```

Can you please help me with that?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/MessagesService ",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccessCall,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });
```

take a look [here](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2012/01/jquery-ajax-examples-by-calling-aspnet.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485536/664479) for an asp version