# Consume a Web API web service in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Right... feel free to call me an idiot in 27 different languages but:

I have started developing a web service using the .NET 4 Web API. I've written a method called GetTransaction that just returns a string. I've published it to an external URL. I'm on a PC connected to the internet and I'm using Firefox.

If I browse to:

```
https://url/service/api/transaction/1
```

in Firefox the browser displays

```
<string>Hello World</string>
```

but if I create a simple .htm file with the following jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://url/service/api/transaction/1',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

I get a response with Status = 200 OK but the Response tab (in Firebug) is blank. No XML.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: what if you remove the dataType: 'xml' bit?

Comment: Are you running your test script from something under `https://url/`?

Comment: No, the test script is just running off my laptop, i.e. file:///c:/users/me/.../etc. Am I hitting a x-domain restriction?

Comment: If I take out 'dataType: xml' nothing different happens.

Comment: Try see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are indeed hitting a cross-domain restriction. I don't use .Net and am not sure if using JSONP instead of XML is an option for you, but if it is, that would resolve your cross-domain restriction and allow you to run it from your local test script.