# Assign href of anchor with jQuery in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to assign the href value of an anchor with jQuery. This href will be a function in my code behind file or any other file. This is how I am doing:

```
$("#btnDownload").attr("href", "/GetFile");
```

But it's not working, it's redirecting to page not found. I have tried this as well:

```
$("#btnDownload").attr("href", "/MyFile.aspx/GetFile")
```

with [WebMethod] attribute but no luck. How can I assign the href of an anchor with the method of my code? And where should I place this function?

Comment: `but its not working`, what does that mean? Does that mean if you look at the HTML in an inspector it doesn't change when the jQuery runs? Maybe it means when clicked it doesn't work?

Comment: @TheSolution when I am clicking on button, Its redirecting to Page not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant make call to the method from  anchor tag using  href attribute. Please make a jquery ajax request to call your method on click on anchor tag.

your anchor tag may look like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btnDownload"></a>
```

and your ajax call would be:

```
$("#btnDownload").click(function(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MyFile.aspx/GetFile", //url to point your webmethod
  data: { name: "sushil", location: "nepal" },//if you have parameters in your method
success:function(){alert('success');},
error:function(){alert('error');}
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call web method by given `href`, check below answer to find the way you can call web method using jQuery:

[How to use jQuery to call an ASP.NET web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service)