# Best (easy) way to fill highcharts with data from database?

Tags: javascript, database, highcharts, fill

The situation is very simple. I have an web application in VB.NET. In some page I generate a report with data from database. At this same page, I need to generate a chart with the same data from database. I´m using a simple line chart with HighCharts.js

I just need to fill the hightcharts javascript with data from the database

Look the code below

```
 $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Feedbacks',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Report',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [ /* here I need to put data from data base */ ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Positive',
                data: [ /* here I need to put data from data base */ ]
            }, {
                name: 'Neutral',
                data: [ /* here I need to put data from data base */ ]
            }, {
                name: 'Negative',
                data: [ /* here I need to put data from data base */ ]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Thanks very much for your support!

Comment: You need to expose db data through a webservice then you should make an ajax request to consume that webservice by getting data you need. Consuming a web service with jQuery -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service . Also useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349598/Introduction-to-using-jQuery-with-Web-Services

Comment: Actually, I was thinking something like call a method in codebehind with jquery ajax and get the data through success callback function

But I need help in how I will fill the javascript with this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare script which get data form database and create JSON, then in highcharts you can use `getJSON()` and paste data as in our examples like: http://jsfiddle.net/usgxh/1/