# How to call .net function from javascript in windows Phone Blank app?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I want to call `.net` function from `javascript` in my Windows phone blank App.
I am creating the UI by parsing the xml. From my xml I am getting the function name as a string. But how to call that function?

Answer (score 0):

.Net is server side code and Javascript is client side code. So, you have to do an ajax call. Probably you want to do something in aspx, but that's not Javascript itself.

Comment: Hello Niels, can you please provide any example for  ajax call.

Comment: it is not server side application. it is a windows phone app.

Comment: Hi @Nikita, a windows phone app is also client side of course. Maybe this stackoverflow question will help: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service)

Comment: hello, i have one string declared inside the Buttonclick event. and i need to display it on UI through javascript.